# Using If condition in For loop in batch

Tags: batch-file

As of now i perform a operation using batch like below.
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO command

- this exeuctes the command on all the folders as i have mnentioned "*" and now I need to skip folders (with name *Shared) in the above command.

Please advice if i can use a IF loop to perform the same and how do i do.
or suggest if there are any simple way to perform

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `%%G` variable to see what the folder name is.  From there, you can get the last 6 characters and see if the value is `Shared`.

We use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` so that we can update variables inside the loop.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO ( 
   SET str=%%G

   IF /I "!str:~-6!" NEQ "Shared" (
       Command
   )
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: Generally good, but note that `SET str=%%G` will fail if folder name contains an `!` character. Can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

Comment: Also DO needs to be removed before Command and comparison should be case insensitive.

Comment: @dbenham - you're correct; I had `ECHO YAY` in there before, and sloppily copied the `DO Command` in.  I don't get any errors with `SET str=%%G` for folders containing `!` though.

Comment: Try against a folder named `"My Shared!"`. Your code will exclude that directory, when actually it should not be excluded. Granted, `!` is fairly rare in file or folder names. But it does happen.

Comment: This does work in case if i wanted to exclude folders (Shared, MY Shared,MY_Shared) *Shared

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use FINDSTR to filter the ouptut of the DIR command and process results using FOR /F.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /ad ^|findstr /lie "shared"') do command
```

Here is a more robust version of LittleBobbyTables' solution that works with `!` in folder names. It also properly does a case insensitive comparison.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%G in (*) DO ( 
  set "str=%%G"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if /i "!str:~-6!" neq "shared" command
  endlocal
)
```